# Why nginx-jwt is so slow when validate token?

Tags: spring, nginx, lua

I am writing a Spring application that does a very simple task.

I want to compare the time to validate token using nginx-jwt (Lua) and validate using pure Java (jose4j).
Doing POST request to an endpoint with authentication header, the endpoint / is where I using nginx-jwt to validate, and /token-java is endpoint using Java.

[nginx-jwt](https://github.com/auth0/nginx-jwt) is a tool using Lua script to validate tokens, and also I write a program to test time validate using java and nginx-jwt.

```
public class ComparePerformance {
     private static final String NGINX_VALIDATE_URL = "http://localhost/";
     private static final String JAVA_VALIDATE_URL = "http://localhost/token-java";
     private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public ComparePerformance() {
        restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    }

    public long getTimeValidateNginx() {
        return getTimeValidate(NGINX_VALIDATE_URL);
    }

    public long getTimeValidateJava() {
        return getTimeValidate(JAVA_VALIDATE_URL);
    }

    private long getTimeValidate(String url) {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Authorization", getToken());
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>("parameters", headers);
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
        }
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        return endTime - startTime;
    }

    private String getToken() {
        return "Bearer xxxx";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ComparePerformance cp = new ComparePerformance();
        long timeNginx = cp.getTimeValidateNginx() / 1_000_000;
        long timeJava = cp.getTimeValidateJava() / 1_000_000;

        LogUtil.log(Level.INFO, cp.getClass(),
            "%nNginx validate time: %dms%n" +
                    "Java validate time: %dms", timeNginx, timeJava);
}
```

}

Here is my configuration in Nginx: (nginx.conf)

```
location / {
    access_by_lua '
        local jwt = require("nginx-jwt")
        jwt.auth()
    ';
    proxy_pass http://localhost; 
}

location /token-java {
    proxy_pass http://localhost/token-java
}
```

Here is my Java validate, I use [jose4j](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bitbucket.b_c/jose4j) to validate using algorithm hs256 - the same as nginx-jwt, below is the method to validate and parse token:

```
public Map<String, Object> parseToken(String JWTToken) throws InvalidJwtException {

    Key verificationKey = new HmacKey(secretKey.getBytes());
    JwtConsumer secondPassJwtConsumer = new JwtConsumerBuilder()
            .setExpectedIssuer(officialIssuer)
            .setSkipDefaultAudienceValidation()
            .setVerificationKey(verificationKey)
            .setRequireExpirationTime()
            .setAllowedClockSkewInSeconds(30)
            .setRequireSubject()
            .build();
    JwtClaims jwtClaims = secondPassJwtConsumer.processToClaims(JWTToken);

    return jwtClaims.getClaimsMap();
}
```

And here is the result:

```
Nginx validate time: 9037ms
Java validate time: 57ms
```

As you can see, Nginx is much slower than Java.

Can someone explain this? 
I'm very confused because I see some pics that Lua is faster than Java.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to ask this question.
I figure out why my nginx-jwt validate token is so slow. Well simply because I using limit request at "/" end point.
When removing that limit, validation at nginx is not slow as validation with Java app